# How to filter and sort data-items according to generated rules which themself are part of the data-structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, data-structures, filter

I need to develop a simple application for filtering and sorting data items according to predefined rules. The application must be able to work with data-items of arbitrary structure, to filter and to sort items based on (pre/defined) property values.

I partially completed the task. But my filtering and sorting does still work with just manually set parameters. How could one achieve filtering and sorting according to generated rule-sets which are part of the to be processed data structure?

As for the provided example, the filtering is based on the `true` values of an item's `disabled` property and the sorting should be done by comparing the values of two item's `rating` properties.

The data structure:

```
const items = {
  "data": [{
    "user": "mike@mail.com",
    "rating": 20,
    "disabled": false
  }, {
    "user": "greg@mail.com",
    "rating": 14,
    "disabled": false
  }, {
    "user": "john@mail.com",
    "rating": 25,
    "disabled": true
  }, {
    "user": "aohn2@mail.com",
    "rating": 34,
    "disabled": true
  }],
  "condition": {
    "exclude": [{
      "disabled": true
    }],
    "sort_by": ["rating"]
  }
};
```

Output of input data:

```
var itemsArr=items.data;
console.log(`Input:`);
itemsArr.forEach((e) => {
    console.log(`user:${e.user}, rating:${e.rating}, disabled:${e.disabled}`);
});
console.log(`_________________________`);
```

Sort by rating:

```
itemsArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    var userA = a.rating.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    var userB = b.rating.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    if (userA < userB) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (userA > userB) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
```

Group by disabled:

```
function groupArrayOfObjects(list, key) {
    return list.reduce(function(rv, x) {
      (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
      return rv;
    }, {});
  };
```

Otput:

```
var groupedPeople=groupArrayOfObjects(itemsArr,"disabled");
result= groupedPeople.true;//will be the true
console.log(`Output:`);
result.forEach((e) => {
    console.log(`user:${e.user}, rating:${e.rating}, disabled:${e.disabled}`);
});
```

Result:

```
Input:
user:mike@mail.com, rating:20, disabled:false
user:greg@mail.com, rating:14, disabled:false
user:john@mail.com, rating:25, disabled:true
user:aohn2@mail.com, rating:34, disabled:true
_________________________
Output:
user:aohn2@mail.com, rating:34, disabled:true
user:john@mail.com, rating:25, disabled:true
```

Comment: I strongly recommend [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) in the sort: `itemsArr.sort((a, b) => a.user.toUpperCase().localeCompare(b.user.toUpperCase()))` for strings

Comment: Sort by rating needs a numeric compare: `itemsArr.sort((a, b) => a - b)`

Comment: And filter on disabled first if you only want disabled

Comment: Thanks for localeCompare. But, I'm interested in how to group according to the conditions specified in the object?

Comment: What is the expected output of `{"exclude": [{"disabled": true}]` and `{"exclude": [{"disabled": false}]` ? - Or, more specifically, exclude is a negative word and disabled also is a negative word. This pattern literally makes a confusion.

Comment: Also is there any chance of having more data inside exclude - like `{"exclude": [{"disabled": true}, {"enabled": false}]`

Comment: @smilyface if for view data: `{"data": [{"name": "John", "email": "john2@mail.com"},
{"name": "John", "email": "john1@mail.com"},
{"name": "Jane", "email": "jane@mail.com"}]}` , set a condition: `{"condition": {"include": [{"name": "John"}], "sort_by": ["email"]}}`  containing two rules - include and sort_by, the result will be an object containing only records named John, sorted by the key email: `{"result": [{"name": "John", "email": "john1@mail.com"},
{"name": "John", "email": "john2@mail.com"}]}`

Comment: From a rule which _"says"_ ... `"exclude": [{"disabled": true}]` ... I expect to actually omit, while processing the data, any disabled item. Thus such items can not be part of the expected output.

Comment: @Ira ... as for the OP's own wording (also from the OP's comments) ... The entire matter is not related to anything close to grouping. Right now ... at least what the expected result tells and what one can get from the not best worded `{ "condition": { /* ... */ } }`-entry ... the only two tasks are **(1) filter the array of data items** according to the provided filter rules (the original `exclude` config) and **(2) sort the filtered data-items** according to the also provided sort config (the original `sort_by` array).

Comment: @Itra ... From the so far provided sole answer / approach are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1):

From one of my above comments ...

> *"@Ira ... as for the OP's own wording (also from the OP's comments) ... The entire matter is not related to anything close to grouping. Right now ... at least what the expected result tells and what one can get from the not best worded `{ "condition": { /* ... */ } }`-entry ... the only two tasks are **(1) filter the array of data items** according to the provided filter rules (the original `exclude` config) and **(2) sort the filtered data-items** according to the also provided sort config (the original `sort_by` array)."*

The beneath solution got provided with the intention of

1. proving, what the OP did ask for, can be done.
2. immediately pointing the weaknesses/shortcomings of the originally chosen rule-related syntax/vocabulary.

And as for (2) the design weaknesses come with

- the filter task which on one hand is capable of multiple key-value based filter conditions but does not allow any other comparison operation than strict value equality.
- the sorting task, based on an array of just keys / property names which already limits the sorting since one neither can tell the to be compared value types in advance (e.g. comparison between number types versus comparison between string types) nor does one know or could guess the final item order (ascending versus descending sorting).

Thus, the following approach already took everything said into account and therefore did apply **structural and naming/wording changes**.

For instance the `sortBy` task which originally allows string items only ... `{ "condition": {"sort_by": ["rating"] } }` ... now features object based sort-by items where one can hint the sort order ... `{ tasks: { sortBy: [{ key: 'rating', order: 'desc' }] } }`

```js
/**
 *  The following function implements a filter task which,
 *  from an array of single key-value pairs (matching entries),
 *  picks exactly those items which feature at least one entry
 *  that matches at least one of the provided key-value pairs.
 */
function getFilteredDataItems(dataItems, matchingEntries) {
  function doesMatchAnyEntry(item) {
    return matchingEntries
      .flatMap(entry => Object.entries(entry))
      .some(([key, value]) => item[key] === value);
  }
  return dataItems.filter(doesMatchAnyEntry);
}
/**
 *  This sorting function implements sort and comparison tasks
 *  which, as long as a comparison value is still Zero, continue
 *  processing an array of single key-value based comparison
 *  items, where an item's array position equals its sort weight.
 */
function getSortedDataItems(dataItems, comparisonItems) {
  function compareByPropertyValueAndSortOrientation(a, b) {
    const orientationMap = {
      asc: 1, ascend: 1, ascending: 1,
      desc: -1, descend: -1, descending: -1,
    }
    let comparisonValue = 0;

    comparisonItems
      // `some` exits early ... here as soon as
      // `comparisonValue` does not equal Zero.
      .some(({ key, order = 'asc'}) => {

        const aValue = a[key];
        const bValue = b[key];
        const orientationValue = orientationMap[order];

        comparisonValue = orientationValue * (
          aValue?.localeCompare?.(bValue) ?? (aValue - bValue)
        );
        return (comparisonValue !== 0);
      });
    return comparisonValue;
  }
  return Array
    // do not mutate the passed data-items reference.
    .from(dataItems)
    .sort(compareByPropertyValueAndSortOrientation);
}

/**
 *  The next provided main function implements
 *  a `reduce` based process which is capable
 *  of sequentially executing one predefined
 *  generic task after the other.
 */
function getProcessedDataItems(data) {
  const taskLookup = {
    filter: getFilteredDataItems,    
    sortBy: getSortedDataItems,
  }
  // ... in case of an undefined tasks
  // return the `data.items` array as is.
  const identity = (items => items);

  const { items, tasks } = data;

  return Object
    .entries(tasks)
    .reduce((dataItems, [key, value]) => {

      const task = taskLookup[key] ?? identity;
      return task(dataItems, value);

    }, items);
}

const data = {
  items: [{
    user: 'mike@mail.com', rating: 20, disabled: false,
  }, {
    user: 'greg@mail.com', rating: 14, disabled: false,
  }, {
    user: 'john@mail.com', rating: 25, disabled: true,
  }, {
    user: 'aohn2@mail.com', rating: 34, disabled: true,
  }],
  tasks: {
    // list of matching entries.
    filter: [{ disabled: true }],
    // list of comparison items (comparison by property
    // value and sorting in a predefiend order) where
    // an item's array position equals its sort weight.
    sortBy: [{ key: 'rating', order: 'desc' }],
    //
    // ... was ...
    // "sort_by": ["rating"],
    //
    // this kind of just property name based sorting
    // is pretty limited since one can not tell whether
    // to sort in ascending or descending order.
  },
};

console.log(
  getProcessedDataItems(data)
);
console.log(
  getProcessedDataItems({
    items: data.items,
    tasks: {
      filter: [{ rating: 34 }, { rating: 25 }, { rating: 20 }],
      // omitted sort order implies (defaults to) 'ascending'.
      sortBy: [{ key: 'rating' }],
    },
  })
);
console.log(
  getProcessedDataItems({
    items: data.items,
    tasks: {
      filter: [{ disabled: false }],
      sortBy: [{ key: 'user', order: 'ascending' }],
    },
  })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: nice: `aValue?.localeCompare?.(bValue) ?? (aValue - bValue)`

Comment: @mplungjan ... Thank you. But I consider it close to being a hack. In projects I use 3 well defined comparison tasks (functions) which are cascade-like joined.

Comment: I liked it because I had to suggest two different sorts in the comments and you just solved that